# Android selection listener

Tags: android, android-view

I need to invoke a method every time an android view (EditText in my case) is selected and to invoke other method every time it's deselected. How can I do it? It seems that there's no "onSelectedListener" or smth like that in android. I need it to work starting with API level 7, if it matters.

Comment: What does _selected_ mean? Are you talking about gaining and losing focus?

Comment: @K-ballo Yes, actually I was googling wrong words - using "focus" instead of "selection" helped me. Maybe it's difficulties of translation from my native language. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean "selected" state for `EditText` a state when you can write a text? Then you should use `setOnFocusChangeListener`.